# Use these pictures to identify me or place 1000 kgs in the South. Who am I?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Can you identify me using these pictures?

[image]

If you could not identify me using the above pictures, then place 1000 kilograms in the South to know who I am.

Hint 1:

> Images 1,2,3,5 indicates some laws. Image 4 indicates where i was born.

Hint 2:

> I am a scientist.

Comment: No it is not a rebus.

Comment: in clock wise direction, i guess first picture is 'fall', 3rd is 'break-in', 5th is 'shadow' and last one is 'directions'... on right track?

Comment: is this a quote or single word?

Comment: Clearly 4 is Hyderabad..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is

> Newton

If you put a Ton, in the South for Image 6 you get

> N(orth)E(ast)W(est)Ton

RIS for that bridge gives me

> England, where Newton was born.

Image 2 appears to be

> An object at rest, about to be acted on by an outside force

Image 3 appears to be

> A forced entry, via an accelerated mass

and Image 5 appears to be

> An object thrown, and in free fall. Being affected primarily by gravity, whose behaviour Newton theorized.

Comment: Hell! I was just about to post it! you beat me to it

Comment: Well you are correct..

Comment: Image 5 represents Newton's third law.. For every action there is an equal and opposite reaction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my idea for the 1000 kgs in the south:

> 1000 kgs is a 'ton'
> so we have to place the letters 't', 'o' and 'n' somewhere in 'south'

I tried all the possibilities but couldn't find anything, maybe someone else can use this idea to find it

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment ?

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo The consensus is that "it is OK", see http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4530/what-is-the-etiquette-for-collaborating-on-the-solution-to-a-complicated-puzzle. But occasionally such posts can spark the anger of frustrated teenagers, and whatnot, depending on who writes the answer, who reads the answer, and what's the current weather in Miami. Let's not worry about this.

Comment: @Matsmath: How is " can spark the anger of frustrated teenagers, and whatnot, depending on who writes the answer, who reads the answer," connected in the context ? More awkwardlly, how "Miami" is entering the scene ?

Comment: @Matsmath: Also, how can consensus be the maker of nonsense "rules" ? The consensus and the actual action which increases the quality, are orthogonal to each other, so the above comments first and last - both parts are completely pointless.

Comment: In case you delete, here's what Matsmath wrote: The consensus is that "it is OK", see meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4530/…. But occasionally such posts can spark the anger of frustrated teenagers, and whatnot, depending on who writes the answer, who reads the answer, and what's the current weather in Miami. Let's not worry about this.

Comment: Or is it 'tonne'?

Comment: upvote for your attempt..